# jmeter: share string array between thread groups

Tags: jmeter

I need to download previously uploaded files with jMeter.

I mean, I've a thread group is engaged to upload several on-the-fly generated files:

[image]

As you can see, when files is just uploaded, an `identifier` is returned and extracted and stored into a `reference-id` variable.

It works, but now I need to download all previously generated and uploaded files using its previously received id.

I don't know how to:

1. share id between several thread groups, and
2. share identifiers into an string array.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way:
You can write your reference-ids in a (csv-)file and import the file by Add/Config Element/(Something with CSV) the other thread group.

Answer (score 0):

In order to share the id between several thread groups you need to convert it into a JMeter Property using [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) or `props` shorthand if you like scripting

Something like:

```
${__setProperty(myProperty,${reference-id},)}
```

or

```
props.put("myProperty", vars.get("reference-id"));
```

once done you will be able to read it in another Thread Group using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) or the aforementioned `props` shorthand like:

```
${__P(myProperty,)}
```

or

```
String myProperty = props.get("myProperty");
```

for thread/iteration specific entries you can use [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function and `${__jm__Thread Group__idx}` special variable as if your test assumes several virtual users/loops the property value will be overwritten each time

And last but not the least, forget about Beanshell, it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting in JMeter

More information:

- [JMeter Best Practices: Beanshell Scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)
- [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/)